# Getting Undefined Error in useContext React

Tags: reactjs, amazon-cognito

I am using AWS Cognito for login authentication. I am able to use it but now I want to apply a session to it. For this, I want to store username and password, and pass them to all the pages that need authentication. I am facing a problem in reading a function for authentication in useContext.

My createContext and Provider function is in Account.js file:

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react';
import { CognitoUser, AuthenticationDetails } from 'amazon-cognito-identity-js';
import Pool from '../../UserPool';

const AccountContext = createContext();

const Account = (props) => {
 const authenticate = async (Username, Password) => {
  return await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const user = new CognitoUser({ Username, Pool });

  const authDetails = new AuthenticationDetails({ Username, Password });

  user.authenticateUser(authDetails, {
    onSuccess: data => {
      console.log('onSuccess: ', data);
      resolve(data);
      // setIsLoggedIn(true);
    },
    onFailure: err => {
      console.error('onFailure: ', err);
      reject(err);
    },
    newPasswordRequired: function(userAttributes, requiredAttributes) {
      // User was signed up by an admin and must provide new
      // password and required attributes, if any, to complete
      // authentication.
      console.log('user attri', userAttributes, this);

      // the api doesn't accept this field back
      delete userAttributes.email_verified;

      // unsure about this field, but I don't send this back
      delete userAttributes.phone_number_verified;

      // Get these details and call
      user.completeNewPasswordChallenge(password, userAttributes, this);
      resolve(data);
    },
  });
});
};
return (
  <AccountContext.Provider value={{ authenticate }}>
    {props.children}
  </AccountContext.Provider>
);
};
export { Account, AccountContext };
```

My main app.js file is:

```
import {Account} from './components/Login/Account'

return (
  <Account>
    <ErrorBoundary context="App">
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppProvider config={this._appConfig}>
          <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
            <Router basename={routerBasename}>
              <WhiteLabelingContext.Provider value={whiteLabeling}>              
                        <OHIFStandaloneViewer />                        
              </WhiteLabelingContext.Provider>
            </Router>
          </I18nextProvider>
        </AppProvider>
      </Provider>
    </ErrorBoundary>
    </Account>
  );
 }
```

My consumer file(LoginPage.js) is:

```
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';
import { AccountContext } from './Account';


const LoginPage = () => {
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const { authenticate } = useContext(AccountContext);

  const onSubmit = e => {
     e.preventDefault();
     authenticate(username, password)
      .then(data => {
        console.log('logged in ', data);
      })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('failed to login: ', err);
  });
 };
```

The error I am getting is: "Cannot read property 'authenticate' of undefined"

Can you please suggest to me where am I going wrong?
Or is there any better way to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is `LoginPage` rendered somewhere within `<OHIFStandaloneViewer /`>?

Comment: No, it is not rendered within `<OHIF... />`, but `LoginPage` is rendered from `<Router basename={routerBasename}>` in which I defined the default page('/') is LoginPage

Answer (score 0):

The evidence suggests that `LoginPage` is not being rendered within the context provider. If it were, the call to `useContext` would return the `{ authenticate }` object you pass to the provider. Instead, it returns `undefined`, which is the default value of the context since you do not provide your own default in the call to `createContext`.

Luckily there's an easy way to test that this is the case. In the call to `createContext`, pass an object that looks like this:

```js
{
  authenticate() {
    return Promise.reject('I'm not inside a provider!');
  }
}
```

If the theory is true, you should see the failure log in the console when `onSubmit` is triggered.